# How can python see MySQL database in xampp

Tags: python, mysql

I used xampp to run MySQL, wrote a line of python code, and got an error message:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost', port=3306, user="root", passwd="")
```

---

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1130, "Host 'bedroom.lan' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

Are there any way for me to use python 2.7 to access the XAMPP MySQL database? If not, do I need to install a MySQL server in the python27 directory?

Answer (score 0):

Fush!

Do you try?

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","bedroom" )
cursor = db.cursor()
```

I tested in Python 2.7 and works.